# issue in installing a package in bioconductor package : scater

Tags: r

I am trying to install an R package called "scater". this is a bioconductor package. the version of R I have is: `R` version `3.4.0`.
I tried this command:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("scater")
```

but still gives this error:

```
  installation of package ‘scater’ had non-zero exit status
```

do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: do you get a specific error over any of the dependencies: it does import a lot of dependencies https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/scater.html

Comment: What did you answer when R asked: "*Do you want to install from sources the packages which need compilation?*" ?